# Receiving "null" in Place of Correct Values

Tags: java, html, rest, path, jersey

I'm currently using Jersey REST to create a webpage that has a list of birds and taxonomy number, with a link to a page specifically about the bird in question. While my links work between the two pages, and my Bird Name and Taxonomy Number appear, I can't get the order or family name to appear. Following is the code in question.

```
@Path("/birdslist")
public class BirdsList extends Birds {

    @GET
    @Path("/all")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String all() {
        Iterator iterator = birdnames.keySet().iterator();
        String page = "<html><title>All Birds</title><body>";
        page += "<p>This is the list of all birds. <br> Click the taxonomy number of the bird you wish to view in detail.</p>";
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Object key = iterator.next();
            String value = birdnames.get(key);
            HashSet fam = family.get(key);
            HashSet ord = order.get(key);
        }
        for (String key : birdnames.keySet()) {
            page += String.format("<p>Name:%s <br> Taxonomy Number:<a href=%s>%s</a></p>",birdnames.get(key),key,
            key);
            getBird(key);
        }   
        page += "</body></html>";
        return page;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{key}")
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getBird(@PathParam("key") String key) {
        String page = "<html><title>Bird #: {key}</title><body>";
        page += String.format("<p>This page contains info on the %s</p>",birdnames.get(key));
        page += String.format("<p>Name:%s <br> Taxonomy Number:%s <br> Family:%s <br> Order:%s</p>",birdnames.get(key),key,family.get(key),order.get(key));
        page += "<p>Please click <a href=all>here</a> to return to the list of all birds.</p>";
        page += "</body></html>";
        return page;
    }
}
```

The family and order are saved in a HashSet that is inside of a hashmap, while bird name is in a hashmap. It was written over from a csv file and converted into hashmaps. Following is that code.

```
public class Birds {

  HashMap<String,String> birdnames;     
  HashMap<String,HashSet<String>> family;
  HashMap<String,HashSet<String>> order;

  /**
   Constructor reads the CSV of all birds
  */
  public Birds() {
    // long path to eBirds assuming Maven "mvn exec:java" is many levels up
    String fileName = "src/main/java/com/example/rest/eBirds.csv";
    boolean firstLine = true;
    this.birdnames = new HashMap<String,String>();
    this.family =  new HashMap<String,HashSet<String>>();
    this.order  =  new HashMap<String,HashSet<String>>();
    try {
      BufferedReader R = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)); 
      String line;
      while (true) {
        line = R.readLine(); 
        if (line == null) break;
        if (firstLine) { // ignore the first line, it's not a bird
          firstLine = false;
          continue;
          }
        String[] fields = line.split(",");
        if (!fields[1].equalsIgnoreCase("species")) continue;  // ignore all but species records
        birdnames.put(fields[0],fields[4]);    // add this bird to name table

        // extract the order name from fields[6]
        String ordername = fields[6];
        if (!order.containsKey(ordername)) { // if needed, create first-time order set        
          order.put(ordername,new HashSet<String>());
          }
        order.get(ordername).add(fields[0]);  // new order member by number for lookup

        // extract the family name from fields[7] -- removing quotes first if needed
        String famname = fields[7].replace("\"","");
        if (!family.containsKey(famname)) { // if needed, create first-time family set        
          family.put(famname,new HashSet<String>());
          }
        family.get(famname).add(fields[0]);  // new family member by number for lookup
        }
      }
    catch (IOException e) { System.out.println("Stack trace: " + e); }
    }
...
  }
```

I've never used HashSets before, that was part of the given info to us. Our assignment was to create a list page and pages specific to each bird and link between the two. I just can't get these last two values to appear correctly. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your use the same key to retrieve all info, but it is not the same. you put field[X] as key, which is different for X=0 and X=7

Answer (score 0):

Here you use the same key for all values, birdnames, family and order:

```
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Object key = iterator.next();
    String value = birdnames.get(key);
    HashSet fam = family.get(key);
    HashSet ord = order.get(key);
}
```

But you initialize them with different keys:

```
// extract the order name from fields[6]
String ordername = fields[6];
if (!order.containsKey(ordername))
{ // if needed, create first-time order set        
    order.put(ordername, new HashSet<>());
}
order.get(ordername).add(fields[0]);  // new order member by number for lookup
```

Here the key would be fields[6] and not the birdnames key.

If you want to keep using the same key, you could do the following for the orders:

```
if (!order.containsKey(fields[0]))
{
    order.put(fields[0], new HashSet<>());
}
order.get(fields[0]).add(fields[6]);
```

Then you can use:

```
HashSet ord = order.get(key);
```

And you will receive all the orders for that bird name.

---

If you don't want to change that and still use the same key you could do something like the following, but that is highly discouraged as it destroys the purpose of using a map in the first place:

```
Set<String> ord = new HashSet<>();
for (String tmp : order.keySet())
{
    if (order.get(tmp).contains(key))
        ord.add(tmp);
}
```

Here ord would contain all the orders for the "key".

As you can see, you need to do much more redundant work, if you don't switch value and "key".

Comment: Okay, so since my order and family names are the keys to their respective hashmaps, is there a way to pull those using the taxonomy number (field[0])? I need to display the key for order hashmap and the key for family hashmap.

Comment: It is possible, but then it doesn't make sense to use maps, as it is fast to retrieve a value by its key but not the key by its value. If you need to do this, then something is completely wrong in the design you (need?) to use. Why cant you use my proposed solution? What doesn't do it what it needs to?